# How to run every n days task at specified time in celery beat?

Tags: celery, celerybeat

I want to run a task every 2 days. But I want to run them at specific time. For example, I want to run a task every 2 days from the current day at 1:00 AM. 
I think `crontab` in celery beat cannot handle this (since it `*/2` will have exceptions during end of the month). So, I was using `INTERVAL` type in celery beat. But `interval` doesn't take time as input (i.e. it looks like it logs the current time (`t`) and runs the task every 2 days at `t`. Is there any way for me to run my task as per my specification?

My current code is like this:

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'add-every-2-days': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': timedelta(days=2),
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}
```